# Agora react webpage recoding

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

I try to make a web service using agora.io.

If two client access to my specific react webpage(you can imagine like webinar page), I want to recording that area(specific webpage? window? tab?).

I try to use agora's cloud recording to send url when I request recording. But I can't record client's mediastream.

```
    <div className="agora-host-test">

      ...

      <div className="portrait-group">
        <div className="portrait" ref={localVideoContainerRef} />
        <div className="portrait" ref={remoteVideoContainerRef} />
      </div>
    </div>
```

agora.io makes each of video tag to ref.

I think when agora access to

Please help me..